# Simple shell script to copy files in S3 using s3cmd on Mac

Tags: macos, bash, shell, amazon-s3, sh

I have a number of files to move within S3 and need to issue a number of "s3cmd cp --recursive" so I have a big list of these commands (about 1200). I basically just want it to do the first one and then the next one and so on. It seems like it should be really simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
s3cmd cp --recursive s3://bucketname/fromfolder s3://bucketname/tofolder/
s3cmd cp --recursive s3://bucketname/fromfolder s3://bucketname/tofolder/
s3cmd cp --recursive s3://bucketname/fromfolder s3://bucketname/tofolder/
...
```

When I run this using "./s3mvcopy.sh" it just immediately returns and doesn't do anything.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Not literally it just returns instantly. Looks like this in terminal: MacHD:Desktop user$ ./s3mvcopy.sh 
MacHD:Desktop user$ ./s3mvcopy.sh

Comment: You're saying that after pressing enter, the prompt still contains `./s3mvcopy.sh`?

Comment: No sorry, its just clear after.

Comment: What does `bash -x s3mvcopy.sh` say/do?

Comment: Instantly returns to the prompt as well. No errors or anything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45323/discussion-between-that-other-guy-and-jeremykrall)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your .s3cfg command under your home directory.

Then in the file make sure you have the following:

```
[default]
access_key = <your access key>
secret_key = <your secret access key>
```

Comment: confirmed these are there. If I run any s3cmd directly via command line it works fine.